# Add protbuf 3.3.0 to Make file

Tags: c++, makefile, caffe, protobuf-c

I use Ubuntu 16.04 vith protobufer 2.6.1, but i want to build [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/)
required for [faster_rcnn_cplusplus](https://github.com/HermannHesse/faster_rcnn_cplusplus) via protobuffer 3.3.0 which I build from GitHub sources.
As I want to install it locally to some folder and use it folder only for 1 program, I folowed the instruction till "make install" command.

And finally my question, could You,please, advice me how can I add my protobuf 3.3.0 to Makefile and what Path should it be. 
(proto 3.3.0 local directory is /home/adzhus/Workspace/Faster-RCNN-CPP-1/protobuf-3.3.0/protobuf-master)

Comment: well...since no one has replied..i will give you my assumption...what worked for me,i did as you did but used version 3.2.0 of protobuf after autoremoving protobuf 2.6,in this case caffe finds it as protobuf goes to the same directory where 2.6 was or links its libprotoc to where 2.6,but make sure you build it with the same gcc as the one you used to build caffe,you can specify it in the gcc flag mhile doing make